# XP screen loses first three characters

Tags: windows-xp, display

Windows XP. The screen loses the first three characters on the left. There is a black band to the right. I want to move the screen three paces to the right. Have tried Mode con ,r,t with combinations of spaces and commas but always returned as illegal. Any suggestions?
Geoff C

Comment: Does this also happen in windows, or only in textmode? does it happen in the bios too? is it possible to make a photo and show us?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "Mode con ,r,t" are but is it possible that the monitor settings themselves need the adjustment, not the computer?  I'm assuming this is an LCD/LED monitor?  Some have an auto-adjust feature that places the video correctly.  Some also have position settings.

Comment: mode con rows, cols is what you use to alter the screen in a command prompt.